# X300 extension board wifi

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-2

On a Raspberry Pi 2 with [X300](http://www.suptronics.com/xseries/x300.html) extension board running Raspbian I can't detect WiFi adapter that comes with X300. Please advice on how to troubleshoot the absence of the adapter in the system.

X300 is connected. Rasbpian wpa_gui doesn't see the adapter.

In `dmesg` I can't see any wireless devices.
`lsusb` outputs:

> Standard Microsystems Corp.
>
> Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub.
>
> Standard Microsystems Corp.
>
> Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse.
>
> A4 Tech Co.

Comment: First please edit your question and include a link to the x300 board. some of us have no idea what it is. Second does the board or adapter appear in the output from dmesg? Are you running their customized image? What other setup have you done?

Comment: @SteveRobillard thanks for the tips. I've added clarification on both points.

Comment: Can you add the output of lsusb?

Comment: @SteveRobillard sorry, the wireless device was my wireless keyboard and mouse dongle. I've removed it and wireless devices disappeared from dmesg output. lsusb output added.

Comment: No output with `lsusb` often means missing firmware. Executing `dmesg | grep firmware` often results in hints about it.